# Can I differentiate $Log(|f(z) |)+ i Arg(f(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis

If we define the complex logarithm as $log(f(z))=Log(|f(z)) |)+ i Arg(f(z))$, where $Log(f(z)) $ is the common logarithm defined for real numbers, how can I differentiate it?

If I assume f(z) is holomorphic the derivative of $Log(|f(z) |)=\frac {f'(z) } {f(z) } $ but from what I know $Arg(f(z) $ is not differentiable. Is $log(f(z)) $ as defined above not differentiable then?

Comment: Within a branch, logz is differentiable, with derivative 1/z.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $f(z)$ is analytic and has a logarithm in a region $R$. Then, within the region where $\log(f(z))$ is defined, we have, by definition of $\log(f(z))$: $$e^{\log f(z)}=f(z).$$  Differentiating both sides, we get: $$e^{\log f(z)}\frac{d}{dz}(\log(f(z))=f'(z),$$ so that $$\frac{d}{dz}(\log (f(z))=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$

If you want to see the derivative in terms of the argument, it is a good idea to use polar coordinates:

Cauchy-Riemann in polar coordinates are given by (for $f(r, \theta)= u(r, \theta)+iv(r,\theta)$) $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}= \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta},\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}=\frac{-1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$$ In this choice, $\ln(re^{i\theta})=\ln r+i (\theta)$ is differentiable. Since the change of coordinate (where valid) is a diffeomorphism, it sends the differentiable function $\ln r+i \theta$ into a differentiable function $\ln|f(z)|+i\arg z$

EDIT: Another way of seeing that $\log f(z)$ is analytic is that $\log f(z):= \int_{\gamma} df(z)/dz$ , where $\gamma$ is a curve within the branch. Within a simply-connected region , the integral is well-defined, in that it is independent of the choice of path, and the antiderivative, in a simply-connected region, of a holomorphic function is holomorphic (one of the many corollaries of Cauchy's theorem).

Comment: So you showed that for my expression of the complex logarithm the Cauchy - Riemann equations are valid and hence it is holomorphic?

Comment: Also, if I set $u=ln r$ then $du/dr$ is not equal to $1/rdu/dv$, how did you define u?

Comment: Actually, you use $u=lnr; v=\theta$ . Then $u_r=1/r; v_{\theta}=1=(1/r)$ Also $v_r=0 $

Comment: Let me edit another way of seeing that logz is analytic.

Comment: One more question : how is $1=(1/r)$, have you taken the domain of $f$ to be the unit circle?

Comment: @Alexander: Sorry for my delay: No, notice you have a coefficient of 1/r in the polar Cauchy-Riemann equations, so that $u_r =1/r (v_{\theta})$